# Android emulator - permission issue when copying files using Device File Explorer

Tags: android, android-emulator

Using Android Studio I try to upload some folder under /data/data/appname/ using File explorer I get this every time.[image]

Comment: Seems that running "adb root" solves the permission issue

Answer (score 0):

Running "adb root" solves the permission issue.